# Tkinter - Entry box - formatted for date

Tags: python, date, tkinter

I would like to have an entry box for typing in dates so that the user can only type it one way.

The entry box before typing would look like this (without the underscores) **`__/__/____`**, and the **`/`**'s are not deleted when the user types the date.

Thanks

Comment: @Tim I'm assuming that the OP wants such an entry box.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible.

Comment: @pydsigner: of course it's possible. It's not directly supported by a single entry widget, but I've seen it done. All it takes is three entry widgets, two label widgets, and some special bindings.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Ah! I can visualize this thing now... I was thinking in terms of one Entry().

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to @Bryan Oakley's major hint, I have come up with this working code.

(Update: threw a few years of programming experience and some recent readers' sharp eyes at improving the code.)

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


class DateEntry(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, frame_look={}, **look):
        args = dict(relief=tk.SUNKEN, border=1)
        args.update(frame_look)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **args)

        args = {'relief': tk.FLAT}
        args.update(look)

        self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self, width=2, **args)
        self.label_1 = tk.Label(self, text='/', **args)
        self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self, width=2, **args)
        self.label_2 = tk.Label(self, text='/', **args)
        self.entry_3 = tk.Entry(self, width=4, **args)

        self.entry_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.label_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.label_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.entry_3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.entries = [self.entry_1, self.entry_2, self.entry_3]

        self.entry_1.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(0, 2))
        self.entry_2.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(1, 2))
        self.entry_3.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda e: self._check(2, 4))

    def _backspace(self, entry):
        cont = entry.get()
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, cont[:-1])

    def _check(self, index, size):
        entry = self.entries[index]
        next_index = index + 1
        next_entry = self.entries[next_index] if next_index < len(self.entries) else None
        data = entry.get()

        if len(data) > size or not data.isdigit():
            self._backspace(entry)
        if len(data) >= size and next_entry:
            next_entry.focus()

    def get(self):
        return [e.get() for e in self.entries]


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('DateEntry demo')

    dentry = DateEntry(win, font=('Helvetica', 40, tk.NORMAL), border=0)
    dentry.pack()

    win.bind('<Return>', lambda e: print(dentry.get()))
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you set the borderwidth of the entry widgets to zero, then place all the widgets in a frame with a borderwidth of 1 (one), it will look like a single widget. Otherwise, excellent work. Don't think of Tkinter as a collection of widgets, think of it more like a box of legos.

Comment: **Wow.**
Not exactly what I was looking for, rather above and beyond it. 
Thank you for the time you put into this !!! 
Thank you @pydsigner and @Bryan! You guys rock :D

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah, I was in a hurry to get this up before going to bed. I'm finishing up an improved version.

Comment: Done. Customizable and doesn't allow non-numeric characters.

Comment: I sometimes got `IndexError` in the three check methods (due to empty fields). I solved the problem by wrapping everything inside those methods `if cont:`.

Comment: For Python 3 simply edit Line 1, changing 'Tkinter' to 'tkinter', also Line 69, add brackets around the print statement : print(dentry.get())

Comment: @Inyoka updated code should work for both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered a very simple solution. I hope someone can find it useful.

```py
self.entry1=tk.Entry(self)
self.entry1.insert(END, "    /    /        ")
self.entry1.config(fg="grey")

def datemask(self, event):
if len(self.entry1.get()) is 2:
    self.entry1.insert(END,"/")

elif len(self.entry1.get()) is 5:
    self.entry1.insert(END,"/")

elif len(self.entry1.get()) is 11:
    self.entry1.delete(10, END)
```

Bind the entry widget

```py
self.entry1.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.datemask)
```